# Remove last commit from remote Git repository

Tags: git

How can I remove the last commit from a remote Git repository such as I don't see it any more in the log?

If for example `git log` gives me the following commit history

```
A->B->C->D[HEAD, ORIGIN]
```

how can I go to

```
A->B->C[HEAD,ORIGIN]
```

Comment: If you have committed it to the repo then I don't think there is a way to remove it.

Comment: @Guarav: I think there is no _polite_ way to remove it. I mean, if all else fails, `rm -rf` on the repo can trash anything. But I think the question I linked to contains a much nicer solution -- that is still impolite if anyone else has pulled the rev.

Comment: The last commit can always be removed from your history. Depending on many factor you may or may not wipe it from people memory completely.

Comment: @sarnold, if it was pushed elsewhere you only trash your idea of repository, not the world :)

Comment: @Michael: ha! excellent distinction.

Answer (score 1240, accepted):

Be aware that this will create an "alternate reality" for people who have already fetch/pulled/cloned from the remote repository. But in fact, it's quite simple:

```bash
git reset HEAD^ # remove commit locally
git push origin +HEAD # force-push the new HEAD commit
```

If you want to still have it in your local repository and only remove it from the remote, then you can use:

```bash
git push origin +HEAD^:"$name_of_your_branch" # e.g. +HEAD^:master
```

Some shells interpret the `^` character. For those shells, either quote/escape or use `~`:

```
HEAD\^
'HEAD^'
HEAD~
```

Comment: Just a note, in zsh use `git reset HEAD\^`

Comment: Use `git reset HEAD~1` on Win machines

Comment: what does +HEAD do? When I did `git log` it added `(HEAD -> approval, origin/approval)` on the latest commit. what does that mean?

Comment: @ASN: it force-pushes the currently checked out branch (which was/is `approval` in your case).

Comment: How to handle 'alternate reality' on other's PC

Comment: To maintain the deleted  commit changes locally  add  the  `--soft `  flag,  `git reset HEAD^ --soft`

Comment: It is possible that the permission on your remote repo branch does not allow the "ForcePush".  To get around that use the information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213673/how-do-i-grant-git-forcepush-permissions-for-pushing-bfg-repo-cleaner-results

Comment: In my case, I wanted to remove a commit starting at a specific hash.
Then I used `git push origin hash:branch -f` to do so.

Answer (score 29):

If nobody has pulled it, you can probably do something like

```
git push remote +branch^1:remotebranch
```

which will forcibly update the remote branch to the last but one commit of your branch.

Comment: You _could_ also do it _if_ somebody pulled it already.

Comment: Absolutely. Though you should only do it if you know what you're doing and what the consequences are. And if do you probably aren't reading this answer.

Comment: which one is the branch name here? before colon or after colon

Comment: @VikasAcharya, both are, first local branch, then remote branch.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker both are same only right? we create branch on local then push it to gitlab.

Comment: @VikasAcharya, it's completely up to you, you can create local branch any way you want and push to any remote branch.