# How do I grant Git 'ForcePush' permissions for pushing bfg-repo-cleaner results to VSTS?

Tags: git, permissions, azure-devops

A person in my company who's an admin on the company's VSTS project created a repo for me, and granted me all permissions on the `master` branch.

Now I need to run [BFG Repro-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) on my repo. It worked great locally, but when I tried to `git push` my mirrored clone, I got:

```
! [remote rejected] user/<someone_else>/<branch> -> user/<someone_else>/<branch> (TF401027: You need the Git 'ForcePush' permission to perform this action. Details: identity <my identity>, scope 'branch'.)
! [remote rejected] refs/pull/<number>/merge -> refs/pull/<number>/merge (TF401027: You need the Git 'ForcePush' permission to perform this action. Details: identity <my identity>, scope 'branch'.)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://<repo>'
```

What permissions should I ask my admin to grant me so I can complete this? How would she do that from VSTS web UI?

Answer (score 84):

To set Force push permission for a branch, it’s located in **Branch Security**. If you are an administrator for the team project, you can also set it by yourself. Detail steps of setting as below:

In the VSTS team project -> Code Tab -> selected the repo you are working for -> Branches Tab -> select the branch you want to set force push permission ->  `…` button -> Branch Security -> set the group you are in or add your account as user -> set Force push to **Allow** -> save changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I wrote in the original post, the admin did that for me on the `master` branch. However, the error suggests I'm missing permissionson  `user/<someone_else>/<branch>`, which presumably the admin can grant me as well, and on `refs/pull/<number>/merge`, for which I have no idea.

Comment: @Jonathan You need the same permission on all affected branches. When the history of those commits is rewritten, it generates a branch new hash identifier for the commits. As a result, the force push is also going to be disruptive for anyone who's been committing to the repo in the meantime, since their commits will have different parent commits.

Comment: @Jonathan Also please make sure your local repo working tree is clean (verified by `git status`). And then make sure target branch with force push permission for you.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently even if i'm a rep admin, i still need to assign these.

Comment: The same for azure.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215134/7851959 above. 
You have to do the same for the branch and for the repository (Code -> Manage Repositories).
Also keep in mind about default configuration: **Project Collection Administrators** group doesn't have the Force Push permissions.

Comment: Seems like the Azure UI may have been changed because I can't figure out how to get this setting to work/stick. There is no "Code -> Manage Repositories" anymore AFAIK). Any tips?

Comment: Is inside settings/repositories, go to the security tab, find your user or group and enable the force push permission