# how to remove the last commit from remote git repo?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-for-windows

how to remove the last commit from remote git repo? It was not added from its local repo. It was added from different local repo by accident. I tried all recommendations and non eworked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove last commit from remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225125/remove-last-commit-from-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

this may help (from GitHub)

#### Removing the last commit

To remove the last commit from git, you can simply run

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If you are removing multiple commits from the top, you can run

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

to remove the last two commits. You can increase the number to remove even more commits.

If you want to "uncommit" the commits, but keep the changes around for reworking, remove the

```
"--hard": git reset HEAD^
```

which will evict the commits from the branch and from the index, but leave the working tree around.

If you want to save the commits on a new branch name, then run

```
git branch newbranchname
```

before doing the git reset.