# Remove git commit on main branch on github

Tags: reactjs, git, github

Just trying to remove the commit here as I've doubled up and I've correct somethings which should not be here example below. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntIWu.jpg)

Just want to delete the top commit so it doesn't show up, I know how to revert or checkout to a previous but cant remove that top commit.

cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225125/remove-last-commit-from-remote-git-repository

Answer (score -1):

**this solution i strongly advise to be carefull if you are working with a team**

Here is a simple approach in up to 4 steps:

0 - Advise the team you are going to fix the repository

Connect with the team and let them know of the upcoming changes.

1 - Remove the last commit

Assuming your target branch is master:

```
$ git checkout master # move to the target branch
$ git reset --hard HEAD^ # remove the last commit
$ git push -f # push to fix the remote
At this point you are done if you are working alone.
```

2 - Fix your teammate's local repositories

On your teammate's:

```
$ git checkout master # move to the target branch
$ git fetch # update the local references but do not merge
$ git reset --hard origin/master # match the newly fetched remote state
```

If your teammate had no new commits, you are done at this point and you should be in sync.

3 - Bringing back lost commits

Let's say a teammate had a new and unpublished commit that were lost in this process.

```
$ git reflog # find the new commit hash
$ git cherry-pick <commit_hash>
```

Comment: ok yes but will that show in the history that the commit is gone like in the example photo? or can you not change that