# How can I remove last commit from git repository

Tags: github

I tried and also google it but never solve this problem. I found this command **git reset --hard HEAD^** it also doesn't work.

Comment: If you have pushed to the repo, it's generally a bad habit to remove the commit.
However if you didn't push the commit you can do the reset trick by specifying origin/head. 
Beware it will revert to the last pushed commit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove last commit from remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225125/remove-last-commit-from-remote-git-repository)

Comment: I will suggest you do the modifications to override your previous commit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

The **git reset --hard HEAD^** instruction does not remove a commit by definition. It just forces the branch to point to the previous (parent) commit (^) on your local repository. To have the same status on the remote repository, you need to force push using **git push <remote (default: origin)> <target_branch> --force**. Be aware this push can erase others' works. You can use **--force-with-lease** instead of **--force** for more secure use.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command git reset --soft HEAD~1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).