# How to push a new development branch to a mirrored gitea repository?

Tags: git, gitea

It seems can't push commits to a new branch to a mirror repository without setting push to upstream.
I created a mirror repository in gitea, it synchronizes from a GitHub repository period. I cloned the gitea repository to my local and created a new branch. Now I want to push the new branch to gitea, it reports that the remote repository is read-only.
"remote: mirror repository is read-only"
Does it mean that it can't push to a mirrored repository and the only way is to convert the repository to a normal one?

Comment: A mirror is typically intended to exactly reflect what it is mirroring, so making it read-only by default would make sense. Otherwise, the next time it is updated from its source, it'll undo what you might have pushed to it.

Answer (score 0):

##### current branch all file over-write with target branch

```
`git merge <branch-name>`
```

##### change branch to branch name

```
`git checkout <branch-name>`
```

##### remove all change merge from new branch

```
`git merge --abort`
```

##### fetch new branch

```
`git pull origin <Remote-branch-name>:<Local-branch-name>`
```

##### fetch all changes from remote branch into local current branch

```
`git pull origin <branch-name>`
```

#### delete local branch

```
`git branch -d <branch-name>`
```

##### alert (do not use this) first use use 'git merge --abort'

```
`git branch -D <branch-name>`
```

#### rename local branch

```
`git branch -m <branch-name>`
```

#### delete remote branch

```
`git push origin --delete <branch-name>`
```

#### undo the most recent local commit in Git? Delete files related to commit

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

##### and So, on

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git push origin +HEAD^:Branch_name
```

##### undo most recent local commit But not delete files

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

###### for last two commit

```
git reset HEAD~2
```

[Remove last commit from remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225125/remove-last-commit-from-remote-git-repository)

###### force fully pull branch

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```